# Wy there is an Error with displaying html-entities Entities in Wordpress PHP-Modul?

Tags: php, wordpress, html-entities

i am not a Developer but a friend told me that maybe someone with a bug in my Wordpress installation can help me here.

On my side, entities like "…" oder "&eur;"  are not interpreted correctly. If I set the php version to 7.4, an associated error message is displayed:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /html/carron.de/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1830
```

It refers to the following line of a php module.

```
function wp_kses_named_entities( $matches ) {
            global $allowedentitynames;

            if ( empty( $matches[1] ) ) {
                        return '';
            }

            $i = $matches[1];
            return ( ! in_array( $i, $allowedentitynames, true ) ) ? "&amp;$i;" : "&$i;";
}
```

Can you tell me what to do here?

Thanks a lot for your time…

Best Ralf

Comment: check the declaration of the global $allowedentitynames - it must be an arrax, not an enum nor an string etc...

Comment: thanks ... where can i find the declaration of the global $allowedentitynames?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug if you upgraded your WP. Please refer to this article for a possible workaround: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47357